# Possible to find the location of a file with just its name in Java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to find the absolute path of a file with as little information as its name known to us in JAVA?I only have a file name with me and I need to send that as an attachment :

```
 String logName = createLogFileName(node);
 String filePath = ?????
 attachFile = File(filePath);
 message.addAttachment(attachFile);
```

The file already exists.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you creating these files? If so then you should save the file path when you do since you need them later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search whole filesystem recursively.

Comment: That sounds like a long procedure!

Answer (score 0):

Does your `createLogFileName` method create the log file in the working directory? If you didn't write it, you'll have to look at the documentation, or examine the implementation, to be sure.

You can get the current working directory with `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

Comment: Yeah it seems like it is creating them in the current working directory.

Comment: So to get the path, you just need to concat the working directory with the file name, with `File.separator` between them.